# Extract information from Datastore using OPEN XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have the following sample XML held in a database field:

```
<datastore multipleDataSeparator=",">
  <group name="BasicDetails">
     <field name="CalculationType">REFUND</field>
  </group>
</datastore>
```

I am trying to extract the value held for `CalculationType` node using the following SQL script:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
DECLARE @idoc int
declare @lstrCalculationType varchar(50)
SET @xml = (
    '<datastore multipleDataSeparator=",">
  <group name="BasicDetails">
     <field name="CalculationType">REFUND</field>
  </group>
</datastore>'
            )


select @xml

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml --Preparing XML handle

select @idoc,@xml 


SELECT 
@lstrCalculationType = CalculationType
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'datastore') --Row Pattern
WITH (
 CalculationType VARCHAR(50) 'BasicDetails/CalculationType'
)

select @lstrCalculationType

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc --Releasing memory
```

However, the output is null for `@lstrCalculationType`. Any guidance or input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the built-in XQuery support to do this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SET @xml = ('<datastore multipleDataSeparator=",">
                 <group name="BasicDetails">
                     <field name="CalculationType">REFUND</field>
                 </group>
             </datastore>')

SELECT 
    @xml.value('(/datastore/group/field[@name="CalculationType"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(25)')
```